# Choosing Data Provider for .Net application

Tags: sql, odbc, oledb, dataprovider

What can you recommend based on your experience on what provider to use? I will be using SQL Server database.

- ODBC
- OLeDb
- SQL

Still, I want this data provider to support Entity Framework for future development.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql server then I will recommend you to go for SqlClient data provider.Since the SqlClient is managed data provider whereas the ODBC and OLEDB are unmanaged data providers.Managed data providers provides many advantages over unmanaged one like data updates are more efficient in managed providers than the unmanaged one etc